# Change style of label when checkbox gets checked - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Hello... I have an ion-checkbox, and when it gets checked, it should change some style of an ion-label.

```
 <ion-label>{{item.itemName}}</ion-label>
 <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked" (ionChange)="check(item)" color="primary"></ion-checkbox>
```

When I click the checkbox, the ion-label associated with that checkbox should get:

```
 text-decoration: line-through;
```

And when it gets unchecked, the text-decoration should get normal again...

I've tried using ion-checkbox:checked in the SCSS, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: Cant you insert a class when it is checked on the parent element and then change the style of the child text with that class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the style attribute binding, like this:

```
<ion-label [style.text-decoration]="item.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none'">{{ item.itemName }}</ion-label>
```

Please take a look at **[this working Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-styles)**.

[image]